# Fetching ProjectSiteUrl from Project Online not working

Tags: c#, csom, project-online

I have written the following code to get `ProjectSiteUrl` property from a project Published in Project Online

```
using (ProjectContext projContext = new ProjectContext(pwaUrl))
{
    using (SecureString securePassword = new SecureString())
    {
        Helper.GetSecurePassword(projContext, securePassword, emailID, password);

        for (int i = 0; i < listGuid.Count; i++)
        {
            #region Load Project
            string spoGuid = listGuid[i].ProjectGuid;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(spoGuid))
            {


                Guid id = Guid.Parse(spoGuid);

                var projBlk = projContext.LoadQuery(
                        projContext.Projects
                        .Where(p =>
                            p.Id == id
                        )
                        .Include(p => p.Id,
                        p => p.Tasks,
                        p => p.TaskLinks,
                        p => p.ScheduledFromStart,
                        p => p.ProjectSiteUrl,
                            p => p.Name,
                            p => p.IncludeCustomFields,
                            p => p.IncludeCustomFields.CustomFields,
                            P => P.IncludeCustomFields.CustomFields.IncludeWithDefaultProperties(
                                lu => lu.LookupTable,
                                lu => lu.LookupEntries,
                                lu => lu.LookupEntries.IncludeWithDefaultProperties(
                                    entry => entry.FullValue,
                                    entry => entry.InternalName)
                            )
                        )
                    );

                projContext.ExecuteQuery();

                poFieldValues.Add(LoadProjectsinPO(projBlk, projContext));

            }
            #endregion
            //if (i > 5)
            //{
            //    break;
            //}
            if (i % 5 == 0)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(sleepDelay);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

On trying to access the ProjectSiteUrl property I'm getting `null`. I used to get the correct ProjectSiteUrl but for last few weeks i'm getting null. There were no changes to the code.

Did something change in the way we access this property in Project Online?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had modified the order of loading properties in Load Query and `ProjectSiteUrl` is loading fine now. Don't know why it is working though. Would be grateful if someone explains this.

```
 var projBlk = projContext.LoadQuery(
                        projContext.Projects
                        .Where(p =>
                            p.Id == id
                        )
                        .Include(p => p.Id,
                        p => p.ProjectSiteUrl, // Moved ProjectSiteUrl as second loading parameter.
                        p => p.Tasks,
                        p => p.TaskLinks,
                        p => p.ScheduledFromStart,

                            p => p.Name,
                            p => p.IncludeCustomFields,
                            p => p.IncludeCustomFields.CustomFields,
                            P => P.IncludeCustomFields.CustomFields.IncludeWithDefaultProperties(
                                lu => lu.LookupTable,
                                lu => lu.LookupEntries,
                                lu => lu.LookupEntries.IncludeWithDefaultProperties(
                                    entry => entry.FullValue,
                                    entry => entry.InternalName)
                            )
                        )
                    );
```

Comment: @sasfrog no  I did not. like some of my other questions where i answered it myself, I dont know why it works.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not surprised you had to move it up based on the query the moment you start going down the path of getting tasks, then custom fields and then lookup values it gets messy.  I'd recommend not getting everything at once just get what you need at a Project Level, then Task Level, Resource Level, Assignment Level etc.  Plus use Odata to grab info out of the reporting database its a lot faster.  The reporting db has the most recent published info so it eliminates any mess someone could have caused using draft data.